# Will I get ideal performance out of a hybrid SSD/Magnetic HDD if I clone it from an existing HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, hybrid-storage

I recently purchased a magnetic/SSD hybrid drive (Seagate ST1000DX001). I'm wondering if I'll get ideal performance from the drive if I simply clone my existing drive to my new one, or would it be better if I install an new OS and reinstall my programs from scratch? I'm concerned the drive might not be smart enough to know where my OS and frequently accessed files are if I just do a clone, as my understanding is that the drive automatically optimizes storage locations over time

Comment: Yes; Any performance gains is built-into the hardware itself

Comment: Yes, but without any "history" on the new drive, it wouldn't really know how to optimize my files, would it? I'm not sure how aggressive their optimizations are.